# merge Orc File at Data Level not Stripe level

Tags: hadoop, hive, orc

I want to do the merge at data level so that number of stripes are reduced. This is because i have files being processed hourly and a lot of smaller ORC files are created per partition.I know hive concatenate can merge files at stripe level. If i concatenate, the file merge is only happening at stripe level like that many stripes are getting added. I end up having multiple stripes with just 2-3 rows. I would want to have lesser stripes with more rows in it.

Answer (score 0):

merge.orcfile.stripe.level=false should work, but I have not gotten it to work on our cluster.

I had to write a custom program that read and combined the files.

Comment: Hi @Joel , we tried doing the same, but then its as good as strip level merge. we have incremental file processing, and this keeps generating multiple files every day. I cannot do an overwrite and create a different table, coz , when overwrite is happening on the table, at that moment the data would be blank. Does you custom program do anything different? Thanks for your input. Much appreciated.

Comment: Our custom program tracks the files it combines into a temporary file.  Then it executes a swap, by deleting the small files and renames the large combined file into it's place.